# Mysql import remote file to local server

Tags: mysql

I would like to import a file located with http protocol into mysql.

I tried it in cmd:

```
    C:\Users\Me>mysql -u root -p grroo_dev < http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/
mine/DB/dump.sql
```

Assembla requires username and password.

However I get:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line interpreter doesn't support HTTP URLs. You need to download the resource first, and load it next. If you have [`wget`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm), for example:

```
C:\Users\Me>wget http://yourusername:yourpassword@subversion.assembla.com/svn/mine/DB/dump.sql  
C:\Users\Me>mysql -u root -p grroo_dev < dump.sql
```

Note that you need to replace `yourusername` and `yourpassword` with your actual username and password that you have for that site.

Comment: I get: Resolving subversion.assembla.com... 1.1.1.1
Connecting to subversion.assembla.com[1.1.1.1]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required
Authorization failed.

Comment: @Odelya: ok, you need to specify the username and password, then. I must have missed that part of your question, will edit.

Answer (score 3):

```
curl http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/mine/DB/dump.sql | mysql -u root -p grroo_dev
```

cURL for Windows is at http://curl.haxx.se/download.html